# setting up USB speaker on Slackware

Tags: usb, audio

So I'm good with Linux, but hardware isn't my strong suit.

I have a USB speaker that I've plugged into my machine, but I can't figure out how to configure Linux to use it.

I see it loaded in `/var/log/messages`

```
Aug 20 12:48:35  usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
Aug 20 12:48:36  usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
Aug 20 12:48:36  usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=0a4f
Aug 20 12:48:36  usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Aug 20 12:48:36  usb 1-2: Product: MINI BOOM
Aug 20 12:48:36  usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Logitech
Aug 20 12:48:36  hid-generic 0003:046D:0A4F.0007: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device
                          [Logitech MINI BOOM] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
```

Based on that last line, I see these files have appeared:

```
0 crw------- 1 root root 240,  0 Aug 20 12:48 /dev/hidraw0
0 crw------- 1 root root 180, 96 Aug 20 12:48 /dev/usb/hiddev0
```

I have modules installed:

```
snd_seq_oss            
snd_seq_midi_event      
snd_pcm_oss            
snd_mixer_oss          
snd_usb_audio         
snd_usbmidi_lib        
snd_rawmidi            
snd_seq_dummy           
snd_seq                
snd_seq_device          
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     
snd_hda_codec_realtek    
snd_hda_codec_generic    
snd_hda_intel          
snd_hda_codec         
snd_hda_core           
snd_hwdep               
snd_pcm                
snd_timer              
snd                    
soundcore
```

But every time I run `alsamixer` , I only see the built-in sound card:

```
┌───── Sound Card ──────┐  
│-  (default)           │  
│0  HDA Intel PCH       │  
│   enter device name...│  
└───────────────────────┘
```

and it's not listed in `/proc/asound/cards`

```
% cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xb1228000 irq 128
```

What am I missing?

========

Edit 1:

```
% sudo lsusb -vd 046D:0A4F           

Bus 001 Device 012: ID 046d:0a4f Logitech, Inc. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            3 Human Interface Device
  bDeviceSubClass         1 Boot Interface Subclass
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Keyboard
[....]
can't get device qualifier: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I suspect I found my problem.  The computer thinks it's a keyboard.

Comment: Is your kernel self-compiled or you're your using the distro kernel? Please check this topic because it's seemingly dealing with the exact same issue: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404684/figuring-out-usb-devices

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov  Thank you.  You're much better at searching than I am.  I'll check that out and see if that helps.